# Unbind event that was bound with .live() jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have the following code:

```
$('#form1').live('submit.check', function()
{
    //code...
});
```

Now when I try the following:

```
$('#form1').unbind('submit.check');
```

that event it still bound to the form.  Is it not possible to unbind an event the that used `.live()` to bind it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see I need to use .die().

Comment: yep antonyms - add-remove, attach-detach, live-recorded